# Asterisk Readout Values From a Database

Tags: mysql, database, asterisk, voip, pbx

I am attempting to create a simple asterisk dialplan application that reads values from a MySQL database whenever a user calls a certain extension.
The table looks like this:

Type.....Number

H          .......... 10

S      ..........   60

P       ..........  40

G        ......... 15

So basically, whenever someone calls, asterisk should readout H 10, S 60, P 40, G 15...
Here's what I have so far:

```
;Answer call
exten => 123,1,Answer()

;Readout results to caller

;hangup
exten => 123,3,Hangup()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [func_odbc](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+func_odbc) or [asterisk realtime architecture](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime)/function REALTIME for that.

Unfortanly both require some db settings and coding, it is not one line of dialplan.

Comment: Hi Arheops, I am aware of the use of ODBC and the AGI, however I am not sure how I will implement the code.
Any further thoughts?

Comment: You have hire expert if you have no programming experience. Or read book,i recommend "Asterisk the Future of telephony"